# Microsoft AppCenter- What is the different between active users and the count of user in top devices?

Tags: analytics, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to understand better the metrics exposed by AppCenter. In the first part of the analytics overview's page, for example, is indicated a number of 139 active users, that are people who have opened and used my application in the selected period ( in this case, the previous 7 day, so I guess that the actual day is out of account). Always selecting as time "Last 7 days", however, the total count in "top devices" section is equal to 318 (distributed between the four top models) and is indicated in the tooltip that it shows "the number of active users for the top used models". So, what is the difference between the two metrics? I ask here because Microsoft's documentation is not complete in this sense. thanks to those who will answer.

Comment: Hey, can you clarify - is 139 metrics for monthly users, weekly or daily? There are 3 different numbers and for me personally that sometimes might be confusing. Usually the top devices more or less match those numbers (if counted through percentile)

Comment: 139 is the metric for weekly user.

Comment: Hm.. And what's the % for top-1 device?

Comment: It is 72.2% (the associated number is 231). Is it possible that the "weekly number" indicates the active user , today included, while the number in "top devices" refers to the last 7 days until yesterday?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Let me reach out to corresponding team though

Comment: I suggest you open intercom ticket (open a ticket through portal -> top right corner, question mark -> Contact support) for assistance with this